# DotNetZip get skipped files

Tags: c#, file, skip, dotnetzip

Until recently I used DotNetZip v1.9.1.8 source code.
It's neccessary to skip locked files throw set property

```
ZipErrorAction == ZipErrorAction.Skip
```

That's work fine, but I need to get list of all skipped files, so I changed the source code on my needs.

Now was made decision to use the last version of DotNetZip (1.9.8) throw nuget-package.
But, naturally, it doesn't have such functional or maybe I don't find him.

Anyone encountered with such a task or know how to work around this without changing the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to handle the `ZipError` event. You can use ZipEntry.FileName to get the file name.

See http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/df17bd70-71d9-0fca-a58d-b41455523c86.htm for more info.

Comment: Thank's, you really helped.
I'm set ZipErrorAction == ZipErrorAction.InvokeErrorEvent and in ZipError event CurrentEntry.ZipErrorAction == ZipErrorAction.Skip.